# Django from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application , No module named Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, mod-wsgi, wsgi

ve been struggling with deploying my Django app, when i do it with 0.0.0.0:8000 everything works fine but as soon as i am using apache then i get Django from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application , No module named Django.

Ive tried changing my python version on Ubuntu 18.04 as well for Python3.6.9 to the 3.9.12 and i get the same error on both versions . i am running it in a VENV as well as Django is installed when i do a pip freeze, ive also tried adding paths in my WSGI directly but same error , my also ive doubled check my conf file as that should not be the problem since i copied and adjusted from my other django app that is running with no problems

here is the code

```
Alias /static /home/YOURUSER/YOURPROJECT/static
  <Directory /home/YOURUSER/YOURPROJECT/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /media /home/YOURUSER/YOURPROJECT/media
  <Directory /home/YOURUSER/YOURPROJECT/media>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/YOURUSER/YOURPROJECT/YOURPROJECT>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/YOURUSER/YOURPROJECT/YOURPROJECT/wsgi.py
  WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/YOURUSER/YOURPROJECT python-home=/home/YOURUSER/YOURPROJECT/venv
  WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

Also ive tried some examples that i read about such us

**sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-python libapache2-mod-wsgi**
**sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3**

but that also did not do anything so i can't seem to get around this error and also in my env python packages Django is there so it is installed in my venv.

i would appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: can you post the error you are gettng?

Comment: hi the error i am getting is the description

Comment: as well as internal server error on the frontend

Comment: I would suggest to add a print(sys.path) in wsgi.py and see if the console output fits exactly your path to the environment without any typos.

Comment: if you can I would see if this solves your problem (it always works for me) as a sanity check. sudo -H pip3 install Django.    I ever exactly figured out how the daemon process python path settings mess with everything

Comment: HI , thanks yeah solved this I had the wrong path in the .conf file and also added the paths in my WSGI file and that fixed it. Not sure how to close this question but thanks.